# php str_replace used in a loop with mail function

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have an html email message assigned to a variable before it is used in a loop, then in the loop I try to use `str_replace` to insert custom values into hooks. So in the below example I have an `{email}` hook which I'm trying to replace with the recipient's email address. My problem is that when I output `$message_final` to the browser the `str_replace` function seems to have done the job. But when I send the email out, all the emails are still left with the `{email}` hook, and it appears that `str_replace` hasn't worked. Any ideas what i'm missing here? Thanks.

```
$message = "HTML email message here";

while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($emails_list)) {
    $email =  $r["email"];
    $message_final = "";

    if(!empty($email)) {
        //Replace hook with something new like an email address
        $message_final = str_replace('{email}', $email, $message);
        mail($email, $subject, $message_final, $headers); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a portion of the actual `$message` that contains the hooks?

Comment: Hmm.. the code you posted here looks all right.. Can you post your 'real' code (including the working `var_dump()` you used to see the message in your browser)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhhhh! Palm to face!! It was something completely different causing the issue. In my mail header I had the message attached there, and I was calling str_replace in the wrong bit of the code. Thanks for all your replies guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You've got no `{email}` string in your $`message` that could be replaced

Comment: the HTML string is too long to post here, but it's in the variable $message

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP's actual `$message` has them.

Comment: I have just tested a general string replace using an e-mail address and your hook, and it works fine.

Comment: @EvanMulawski: yes, me either

Comment: I think the OP will find the problem via debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid and works flawlessly. The problem lies somewhere else.

There are few things you might want to check:

- `str_replace` is case sensitive, are you sure it's {email} and not {EMAIL}?
- does $message contains valid message? try printing it out the browser, open it's source code so you can see additional html tags parsed by browser and check whether it's correct

By the way - you should consider using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. The method you're using by default combines arrays created by `mysql_fetch_row` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` into one, so it takes 2 times more space